# using "to" with modified "home"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

My grammar reference book says that I can't use preposition "to" with adverb "home":

> I'm tired. Let's **go home** now.

not

> I'm tired. Let's **go to home** now.

But what if I want to specify whose home it is? Should I also drop "to" then?

In short, should it be

> You know what?! I have an idea. Let's **go to your home** now.

or rather

> You know what?! I have an idea. Let's **go your home** now.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is because in some cases, the word *home* is **not a noun, but an adverb!** Do you use an article with an adverb? Say- I am ***a*** here? Nope! It's *I am here.* Likewise, *I am home.*

Let's discuss some cases...

If it's others' home, you include prepositions *to, at.*

> Let's go **to** your home 
>  Where's Sara? ~ She's **at** her home

Interestingly, you drop everything while indicating someone's home!

> *Where are you? I'm at Sara's!*

If it's about your presence and if it is your home, you drop 'at'

> I'm home 
>  I'll go home 
>  I'll be back home tomorrow

If you are using a pronoun 'my,' you add *to.*

> Let's go *to* **my** home

If it's *not* about your presence and the matter is different, you use *at/in*

> I forgot my keys *at* home